# How to redirect to another page when a dynamic route is not found in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to redirect users when they enter a dynamic route that does not exist. The dynamic route points a field inside a statically defined fields array.

This is my current code for the page:

```
import { fields } from "@/data/fields";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return fields.map((field) => ({ slug: field.slug }));
}

const getField = async (slug) => {
  return fields.find((field) => field.slug === slug);
};

const FieldPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const field = await getField(params.field);

  return <>{field.name}</>;
};

export default FieldPage;
```

Is there is some `if (!field) // redirect or throw error` that I can implement in my code so that this works, that would be appreciated. Currently, I have tried doing so in `getField`, but it throws a 500 error in build mode.

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented with NextJS's API and I found an answer:

```
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

// ...

const FieldPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const field = await getField(params.field);

  if (!field) redirect("/");

  return (
    <>
      <div>{field.name}</div>
      <div>{field.slug}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The `redirect` function instantly redirects the user back to the `/` page when there is no field found in the static dataset. You can also use `NotFound` to redirect to the `not-found.js` page defined in the file system if you need to display a not found (404) error. Hope this helps someone!